# How to click on a link on page load in html?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I have a page with the following link:

```
<a id="id" href="{{ stream.video_url }}" style="text-decoration: none;" download="{{ title }}.{{ stream.extension }}" target="_blank" >Download</a>
```

I want to automatically activate this  when the page loads. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the point of having a page which navigates to a different URL as soon as it loads? That's just slow and convoluted. Use an HTTP redirect instead.

Comment: Is this for an angular app? ...or are you rendering with handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('id').click()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this with event listeners and the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('id').click()
});
```